# What's the infinitive of this verb (verschied)?

Tags: verb, conjugation, past

I’m having a very hard time looking up the infinitive of this verb from *Aschenputtel:*

> Darauf tat sie die Augen zu und verschied.

Google Translate renders this as:

> Then she opened her eyes and left.

Is this translation correct? And if it is, what is the infinitive of the verb ***verschied***? I cannot find it anywhere. I assume this is the 3rd-person singular past tense.

Comment: Are you sure it was translated as "opened her eyes"? Should be "closed her eyes".

Comment: It was translated that way. You can copy/paste the sentence into Google Translate and see for yourself.

Comment: I'm very glad you made that correction, though, as I too was suspicious.

Comment: Google translate returns "... closed her eyes ...".

Comment: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/verschied

Comment: Dieser Onlineübersetzer https://www.deepl.com/translator , den ich aber erst seit kurzem kenne, liefert, wie mir scheint, meist brauchbarere Ergebnisse.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Oh, I'm using the Google Translate app for iPhone. Perhaps that explains the difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The infinitive is "verscheiden". It's an old fashioned word for "sterben" (to die). Sometimes you can also see "aus dem Leben scheiden" which means the same, but is less old fashioned and more formal.

Comment: Thanks! That's very helpful. I just realized how useful it is to look up **scheiden**, since verschieden is hard to find (at least on Wiktionary and Collins German-English dictionary).

Comment: @ktm5124 You need to look up "verscheiden", "verschieden" is already past tense.

Answer (score 3):

The infinitive *verscheiden* is more closely translated by "to pass away". More important is here that your translation got the eye movement wrong. A correct translation would be "On that she closed her eyes and passed away." *Darauf* refers to what happened immediately before this sentence, and the preposition *zu* in the split verb *zutun* means "closed".